# Which direction to take for developing 3D interactive imagery features

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d

I will keep this simple. I am looking everywhere to find something to create 3d tour of an interior similar to photosynth and gmaps street view but **only with javascript**.

Seadragon is the closest thing I found but its not 3d. Sorry if this is too simple but please let me know if you know any API that this can be achieved with.

Thanks a bunch

[I need this to be working with current usual web technologies so HTML5 solutions won't help]

Here are some stuff I found but not exactly my ideal:

1. [jQuery simple panorama viewer](http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery.panorama/) but this is not exactly sleek/intuitive but does have a appeal as in terms of scalability, it will not require members to spend so much time taking 100s of photos to create a 3d model of a space.
2. of course Microsoft [zoom it or seadragon](http://zoom.it/) which is really sleek and also doesn't need excellent photography skills but doesn't produce 3d models
3. [Photosynth](http://photosynth.net/view.aspx?cid=7c56bda2-4ac7-41df-8fc6-83f91089e721) and [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) are great but even though I am thankful to Itay Moav with his/her post below I really want and need to move away from expecting people to have a plugin on their system in order to access a service as this has a huge user experience down turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look for a 3d space-filling-curve. A 3d sfc reduces the 3d complexity to a 1d complexity. It's a bit like an octree and a fractal. For 2d you want to look for a 2d space-filling-curve. You want to look for Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Unity, if you do not care about Linux users (Apple users are good).
It even has a Javascript API

Comment: This similar to Photosynth that does have javascript API too only exposes methods to control an object which effectively runs in a browser plugin, which seems to be unity web player in this case